# Jquery clone() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Html code:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td class="to">ABC</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div class="from" style="display:none;">
    <label>
        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Number"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

and this javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          var values = [12,11,15];
          var cloned = $('div.from').find('label').clone();
          $('td.to').empty();
          for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
              cloned.find('input').val(values[i]);
              //console.log(cloned);
              console.log(cloned.find('input').val());
              $('td.to').append(cloned);
          }
});
```

I am here trying to clone the nested '`label`' from the hidden div '`div.from`' and set one of the value from the '`values`' array and append to empty '`td.to`' using the same cloned object. As far as I know, the last value of the array seems to be appended after cloning. The result should have been three cloned nested labels with value populated in the input box from the '`values`' array.

Here is jsbin link : http://jsbin.com/yuyaqu

Comment: You're only creating one clone, so why would it insert more clones, all `append` does is move that one clone, it doesn't create new clones

Comment: Ok thank you. I thought just reusing the cloned object, changing the property and appending the value would save different instances of the cloned one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `clone()` once per iteration, so put that line within the `for`:

```
var values = [12,11,15];
$('td.to').empty();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    var cloned = $('div.from').find('label').clone();
    cloned.find('input').val(values[i]);
    $('td.to').append(cloned);
}
```